# Tornado AsyncHTTPClient() chunks

Tags: tornado

I am currently fetching the body of a URL with the following code:

```
   httpClient=AsyncHTTPClient()  

    try:
       response=yield httpClient.fetch(url)

       # do something with response.body


    except (HTTPError, IOError, ValueError) as e:
       pass
```

However fetching the whole body doesn't seem to be an efficient way to perform this because I am search for a piece of specific information in the URL. Is it possible rather then fetching the entire body of the URL to fetch it in chunks and stop once I find what i'm looking for, or continue to fetch if need be?

Also I'm doing this for a number of URLs. I saw you could use the following:

```
httpclient.HTTPRequest(url='[some_big_request]', streaming_callback=self.on_chunk)
```

However once I enter the callback how do I get the information I need back out from that function? I need to combine that value with values I obtained from the other URLs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `streaming_callback` with a closure or partial:

```
def f():
    response = yield client.fetch(url, functools.partial(self.on_fetch, url))

def on_fetch(self, url, chunk):
    # do something with chunk
```

It's not currently possible to cancel a fetch from within a `streaming_callback`; the download will continue to run to completion.

Comment: Ok thanks Ben. Actually the only reason  I wanted to do this was to potentially save bandwidth by halting the fetch once I found what I wanted... I have since read about parallelism of fetches and think that might be a better alternative since I was loading serially before

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `streaming_callback` of [`tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#request-objects).

> If set, `streaming_callback` will be run with each chunk of data as it is received, and `HTTPResponse.body` and `HTTPResponse.buffer` will be empty in the final response.

Sine the callback can be a closure, it can access data outside. Define this function in the block that calls `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.fetch`. The you can access everything necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that do I need to decorate the callback?

Comment: Also once in the callback and I find want I need how do I get the fetch to stop executing?